# Store the data received from as Json in an array and display results in a tableView in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4

The modal for Response is below:----

```
struct Welcome: Codable { let response: Response }

struct Response: Codable { let data: [Datum] }

struct Datum: Codable { let id: Int let gmt, abbreviation, zonename: 
String let region: Region let offsetSeconds: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id, gmt, abbreviation, zonename, region
    case offsetSeconds = "offset_seconds" 
}
}

enum Region: String, Codable { case africa = "Africa" case america = "America" case asia = "Asia" case atlantic = "Atlantic" case australia = "Australia" case e = "e" case europe = "Europe" case indian = "Indian" case pacific = "Pacific" } And I am using below code for parsing:---


session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }
        if let data = data {
          print(data)
            do {
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                let anyth = try jsonDecoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: data)
                for boss in anyth.response.data {
                    print(boss.zonename , boss.gmt)

                    let biggboss = boss

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
```

I want to store the data received from the API in an array so that I could populate the table view. The array needs to be global and of type same as that of the struct but I am stuck!!!!!!!

Comment: Can you please print and show the response you are getting from server?

Comment: Similarly, a large number up to 355 entries are there with Unique details but I'm mentioning a few                                                                
Pacific/Enderbury -12:00
Pacific/Kwajalein -12:00
Pacific/Niue -11:00
America/Adak -11:00
America/Nome -11:00
Pacific/Apia -11:00
Pacific/Fakaofo -11:00
Pacific/Midway -11:00

Comment: You can store this by declaring a global variable and reload the `tableView` with that. What kind of problem are you having? Can you please be a little more specific?

Comment: The Problem is response comes to Welcome Struct: and  let anyth = try jsonDecoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: data) . where Welcome is not an array  if I do as you say which I am doing  : var array = [Datum]()  and then if i do self.array = try jsonDecoder.decode([Data].self, data). no response is recieved as response comes in Welcome